# Inversion of Control on a list

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have been thinking about how Inversion of Control would work when working with lists. For example somthing like this would work fine:-

```
public class MyClass
{
private readonly IMyInterface _instance;

public MyClass(IMyInterface instance)
{
   _instance = instance;
}
```

Is the below violating the Open/Closed SOLID Design Principle, and if so how can the list be implemented using IoC like in the above example?

```
private readonly List<IMyInterface> _interface;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _interface= new List<IMyInterface>();
        _interface.Add(new Class1());
        _interface.Add(new Class2());
        _interface.Add(new Class3());
    }
...
```

What I mean here is how do I implement a list collection and pass it to the constructor using IoC?

Comment: Why don't you inject the list via the constructor as you did above?

Comment: @YacoubMassadDo you have an example?

Comment: It is as simple as `public MyClass( List<IMyInterface> list) { _interface = list;}`

Comment: Keep in mind that this may be a DI anti-pattern, as spelled out in Steven's excellent article: https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99  You may be better off injecting runtime data through explicit methods rather than the constructor.

Comment: ok and then how would I then add the classes to the list without using the new keyword?

Comment: @user1319501 creating runtime data is not the same as instantiating dependencies.  You HAVE to create data at some point.  That's ok.  What you don't want to create internally are dependencies.

Comment: Bear in mind that not all dependencies must be injected, nor need to be whilst still adhering to SOLID design principles: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ploeh/2006/08/24/volatile-dependencies/

Comment: Down voting without explaining why really helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to archive dependency injection (DI).

1. Constructor injection: `public MyClass(List<IMyInterface> tobeInjectedList)`
2. Property injection: `public List<IMyInterface> TobeInjectedList { get; set; }`
3. Method injection:

   ```
   List<IMyInterface> _injectedList;
   public void Inject(List<IMyInterface> tobeInjectedList) 
   { 
       _injectedList = tobeInjectedList; 
   }
   ```

A side problem I can notice from you code is that you are excessively using the `new` keyword which will make you class heavily depend on a bunch of other classes, basically a maintenance nightmare. I suggest Factory design pattern to overcome this problem.

http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern